# How can I convert my imported model to a sequential model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've got an imported model with type of `'keras.engine.training.Model'` and I want a Sequential model.

I tried this:

```
model = ..imported model..
seq_model = Sequential()
for layer in model.layers:
    seq_model.add(layer)
```

But it said that "ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs."

Comment: Why do you need a Sequential model? Note that if the model has a non-sequential structure, you cannot convert it to Sequential

Comment: I'd like to use a fit_generator with this imported model. But when the first epoch finished, it stops and doesn't do anything. I read that the model type should be the problem (it should be a Sequential) but when I tried to convert the model I got the error message above.

Comment: No, that is incorrect, fit_generator works fine in functional Models, I use it every day.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to insert ResNet, Please check [functional API](https://keras.io/models/model/) to use it as an output layer.

However, *e.g:* if you're using VGG16 please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772006/converting-vgg-functional-model-into-sequential-model-in-keras).

Comment: Actually, I tried an EfficientNet to import, but in the VGG16 link, it's not clear to me how can I use this in my code.

Comment: What I meant was `Sequential(layers=functional_model.layers)` this part and check whether your model gets bigger as stated in that question. If so, you can utilize the answer in that question.

Comment: I tried but I got the same error: "ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs."